# Bootstrap Modal not showing footer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, bootstrap-modal

I'm using two different Bootstrap modal components on a view in an ASP.NET Core MVC application. For the second modal, the footer is not showing even though the markup is pretty similar to the first modal. The footer of the first modal is shown as expected.

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="firstModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="firstModalTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="firstModalTitle">First Modal</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" />
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="secondModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="secondModalTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="secondModalTitle">Second Modal</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" />
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Each of the modals is shown by clicking a corresponding button, but each button is setup in a slightly different way.

```js
$('#button1').click(function (e) {
  var success = doStuff();
  if (success) {
    $('#firstModal').modal('toggle');
  };
});
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#secondModal"></button>
```

No errors are shown in Chrome web developer tools.
What could be wrong here?

Comment: try $('#firstModal').modal('show');

Comment: The problem is not that the modal is not showing. The modals show, but the footer (with the modal-footer CSS class) of the second modal is not shown. When I inspect the rendered html, the modal-footer div is not rendered in the modal-content div. What could be the reason for that? I also tried to give the modal-footer divs an unique id, but that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I suppose the problem is in your jquery and how you add content to your 2nd dialog or in you div.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution now. There is a dropdown list in the body of the modal that's populated by some Javascript.

```html
<select class="form-control" />
```

Changed the markup to:

```html
<select class="form-control"></select>
```

Now the footer is properly shown as well.